# How to specify the country code for the Spotify Web API in Android?

Tags: java, android, spotify, retrofit

In my android application, I am trying to get an artist's top ten tracks. I'm using a [wrapper](https://github.com/kaaes/spotify-web-api-android/) for the Spotify Web API. To get the artist's top ten tracks you have to provide the `getArtistTopTrack(id)` method with the artist's `id`.

Here's my code that is meant to do that:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_top_ten);

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    String artistID = "";
    artistID = intent.getExtras().getString("ID");

    FetchTopTenTracksTask topTenTracksTask = new FetchTopTenTracksTask();
    topTenTracksTask.execute(artistID);
}

private class FetchTopTenTracksTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Tracks> {

    @Override
    protected Tracks doInBackground(String... params) {
        SpotifyApi api = new SpotifyApi();
        SpotifyService spotify = api.getService();

        return spotify.getArtistTopTrack(params[0]);
    }
```

The error that I am getting is

```
E/AndroidRuntime(2882): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
E/AndroidRuntime(2882): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
```

and it was caused by `doInBackground`. My thoughts are the bad request is caused by this line of code because I need to specify a country code for the search (the API requires this) but I don't know how to.

```
return spotify.getArtistTopTrack(params[0]);
```

The correct endpoint for getting an artist's top tracks is

```
GET https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/{the artists id}/top-tracks?country={ISO 3166-1 alpha 2 country code}
```

But when I checked the LogCat to see what endpoint it was using it turned to be an incorrect one

```
D/Retrofit(2882): <--- HTTP 400 https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/{the artist id}%3Fcountry%3DIE/top-tracks (59ms)
```

As you can see, the country code which is "IE" is appended to the artist `id`, like this: `"%3Fcountry%3DIE"`. This is what is causing the error, because the request could not be understood by the server, due to malformed syntax.

Can someone show me how I can append `"?country={country code}"` to the endpoint, instead of having it right after the artist id?

Answer (score 1):

To provide a solution to my own question:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_top_ten);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    String artistID = "";
    artistID = intent.getExtras().getString("ID");

    FetchTopTenTracksTask topTenTracksTask = new FetchTopTenTracksTask();
    topTenTracksTask.execute(artistID);
}

private class FetchTopTenTracksTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Tracks> {

    @Override
    protected Tracks doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {
            String artistID = params[0];

            Map<String, Object> options = new Hashtable<String, Object>();
            options.put("country", "IE"); //Can be any country code here 

            SpotifyApi api = new SpotifyApi();
            SpotifyService spotify = api.getService();

            return spotify.getArtistTopTrack(artistID, options);
        }
        catch (RetrofitError retrofitError) {

            Log.d("Retrofit Error: ", retrofitError.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }
```

[Here](https://github.com/kaaes/spotify-web-api-android/issues/82) is where I got the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use,

```
import com.neovisionaries.i18n.CountryCode;

try{
....
CountryCode country = CountryCode.DE;
GetArtistsTopTracksRequest request = SpotifyApi.getInstance().getArtistsTopTracks(artistId, country).build();
```